# Running Rspec tests on Pundit policies not cleaning up data after each test

Tags: rspec, ruby-on-rails-5, pundit

Rails 5.2 Rspec 3.7 Pundit 1.10

The following Rspec test for my policy fails with an error:

spec/policies/proofreader/dashboard

```
describe Proofreader::DashboardPolicy do
  subject { described_class }

  context 'accessing the proofreader dashboard' do

    permissions :index? do

      it "denies access to admins" do
        expect(subject).not_to permit(FactoryBot.create(:admin))
      end

    end
  end
end




Error:      ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validation failed: Email has already been taken
```

This test passes the first time when the database is clean but then fails subsequently.

My User Factory uses a sequence so the email is different:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :user, aliases: [:client] do
    sequence(:email) { |n| "tester#{n}@example.com" }
    password 123456
    password_confirmation 123456

    factory :admin do
      after(:build) {|user| user.admin = true }
    end

    factory :proofreader do
      after(:build) {|user| user.proofreader = true }
    end

    factory :admin_proofreader do
      after(:build) {|user| user.admin = true && user.proofreader = true}
    end

  end
end
```

Why am I getting this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: Ever figure it out?